# CronExpression day-of-week with 'L' character

Tags: java, spring, cron

I'm trying to understand how cron expression works for day-of-week field with 'L' character. I'm using spring 5.3.24.
There is a method `org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression.parse` with description:

> In the "day of week" field, L stands for "the last day of the week". **If prefixed by a number or three-letter name** (i.e. dL or DDDL), it means "the last day of week d (or DDD) in the month".

Looks like it can be used without prefix, but it doesn't work without prefix and throws exception for expression `0 0 1 1 * L`:
`No day-of-week before 'L' in '" + value + "'`
Am I missing something or does the description not match the actual code?

Comment: There was a mistake in the Java Doc. Ticket was created and fixed - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29884

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to tell Spring Cron what last days of the month you need. 'L' should be prefixed with either a number (1..7) or three later-day identifiers (MON..SUN)

Examples:

```
0 0 0 * * 5L                last Friday of the month at midnight

0 0 0 * * 1L                last Monday of the month at midnight

0 0 0 * * THUL              last Thursday of the month at midnight
```